# Onclick div to change background style of different div looses some styling css

Tags: image, html, background, onclick

I think this is actually very simple to fix, but I'm stumped!

I have set a background image for a div using the style *background-size: cover;* which makes it fill the div. This works perfectly.

The problem comes, as I have an onclick command on the page to change the background image, which again is fine. The only problem is that the *background-size: cover;* seems to be lost when I change the background image.

I was wondering if adding the following to the onlick change style (as I have done with *no-repeat center center fixed*), but when I do, I break everything.

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="
              document.getElementById('backgroundimage-gallery').style.background = 'url(images/galleries/art/<?php echo $row_images['name']; ?>.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed';" >
              <img src="images/galleries/art/<?php echo $row_images['name']; ?>.jpg" alt="" width="76" height="42" />
              </a>
```

CSS

```
#backgroundimage-gallery{ 
  background: url(images/backgrounds/galleries/photos-of-site.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I haven't posted that for the simple reason that it's attached to a container div that wraps round everything. I'll try and create a jsfiddle on it.

Comment: I've made a fiddle here, and this shows the problem well I think http://jsfiddle.net/rSUXH/

Comment: Finally got round to sorting it. Thanks so much, works like a chalm, always good to learn something from here x

Comment: Glad i could help - do you still need some help with your other questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the console of the chrome dev-tools and enter `var el = document.getElementById('backgroundimage-gallery');` you can test how you can set the background  by by typing  `el.style.background = ....`

I have not tested how to set the style via javascript [using the shorthand-property for `background`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background). But i assume that the cause for your error lies there.

This **[demo should be what you are looking for](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cqznr)**

```
function setImage(theme)
{                           
    var imageUrl = "http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/774143.png?theme=" + theme;
    var el = document.getElementById('backgroundimage-gallery');    

    el.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    el.style.backgroundPosition = 'center center';
    el.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imageUrl + "')";
    el.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
}
```

And this html

```
<div class="container" id="backgroundimage-gallery">
   <div class="image-item">
     <a href="#" onclick="setImage('hotdog')" >
        <img src="http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/774143.png?theme=hotdog" 
             alt="" width="76" height="42" />
     </a>
  </div>        
  <div class="image-item">
     <a href="#" onclick="setImage('dark')" >
        <img src="http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/774143.png?theme=dark" 
             alt="" width="76" height="42" />
     </a>
  </div>            
</div>
```